# Adding code for Comment Boxes on Shopify Blog post in article.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Im trying to add code back into shopify to allow for a comments box at the bottom of blog posts.

from my investigating, the code should exist in article.liquid, however it looks like the original developer deleted it.

I have tried entering code from Shopifys example https://shopify.github.io/liquid-code-examples/example/comment-list which produced no changes (Also I can't see there being an option to 'moderate' the comments, ideally we want to check them before they're posted on site.

Also tried a code from Github https://github.com/Shopify/Timber/blob/master/templates/article.liquid, which resulted in the below image. This code mentions 'moderate', but it didn't work.

[github code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8lL.png)

Has anyone experience similar issue?

this is the current article.liquid code:

```
<div class="small-12 columns">

    <article class="single-article">

        <div class="article__title">
            <h1 class="impact alpha">{{ blog.title }}</h1>
            <h3 class="impact gamma">
                <time pubdate datetime="{{ article.published_at | date: '%Y-%m-%d' }}">{{ article.published_at | date: '%b %d, %Y' }}</time>  |  {{ blog.title }}
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="article__feature-image">
            <img src="{{ article.image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ article.image.alt }}">
        </div>

        <div class="article__content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 columns rte">
                    {{ article.content }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="article__paginate">
            {% if blog.next_article or blog.previous_article %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 columns rte">
                        <p class="clearfix">
                          {% if blog.next_article %}
                          <span class="left impact epsilon">{{ '&larr; Next Post' | link_to: blog.next_article }}</span>
                          {% endif %}
                          {% if blog.previous_article %}
                          <span class="right impact epsilon">{{ 'Previous Post &rarr;' | link_to: blog.previous_article }}</span>
                          {% endif %}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="article__author">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 columns">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="author-image small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ article.user.email | md5 }}?s=100" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="author-details small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            <h4 class="impact epsilon">Written by {{ article.author }}</h4>
                            <p>{{ article.user.bio }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="article__social clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-8 small-centered columns">
                    <h4 class="epsilon impact">Share This</h4>
                    <br>
                    {% include 'snippets_share' %}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </article>


</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to copy the code from the same theme to article.liquid or just compare and repair the code that was deleted by the developer in the past.

Comment: The problem is we didnt use an out-of-the-box theme code and the developer we used was through an agency we cut ties with years ago.

Comment: Which theme you are using from the out-of-the-box?

Comment: please show your `article.liquid` or `article-template.liquid` code.

Comment: Ive added the current code into post

Comment: Im not sure which theme they chose, it was over 5 years ago and the team is new :(

Comment: the one you shown is template for blog, not article

Comment: i dont understand, the folder is called article.liquid?